Unaligned relative date range
How to define Relative date range in time dimension to query exactly last 24 hours with no time unit alignment?
Assuming current time is 2024-12-10T15:35:48.000.
How to query data from 2024-12-09T15:35:48.000 to 2024-12-10T15:35:48.000? So no "hour" alignment.
from 24 hours ago to now returns range 2024-12-10T15:00:00.000 to 2024-12-11T15:59:59.999
last 24 hours returns range 2024-12-10T15:00:00.000 to 2024-12-11T14:59:59.999
I could define it in seconds:
last 86400 seconds ago to now returns range 2024-12-10T15:35:48.000 to 2024-12-11T15:35:47.999. That is close to my needs but also harder to work with internally.
